# Can not map native sql result into dto using @Query annotation

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have followed JPA interface projection process to map native SQL result into a custom DTO but still, I am getting result in `AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap` format. How can I map the result into desired DTO class?

> **This is the repository class**

```
@Repository
public interface SubjectMarkingCriteriaRepository extends JpaRepository<SubjectMarkingCriteria,Long> { 

    @Query(
            value = "select smc.id as id ,c.class as academicClass,s.subject as subject,mc.criteria as criteria " +
                    "from subject_marking_criteria smc " +
                    "join subject s on smc.subject_id = s.id " +
                    "join marking_criteria mc on smc.marking_criteria_id = mc.id " +
                    "Join class c on s.class_id = c.id ",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<ResultDTO> findAllByParam();
}
```

> DTO interface

```
public interface ResultDTO{
        Long getId();
        String getAcademicClass();
        String getSubject();
        String getCriteria();

}
```

> Entities are :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "subject_marking_criteria")
public class SubjectMarkingCriteria {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="subject_id")
    private Long subjectId;

    @Column(name="marking_criteria_id")
    private Long markingCriteriaId;

}


@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "subject")
public class Subject {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="subject")
        private String subject;

        @Column(name="bn_subject")
        private String bnSubject;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "marking_criteria")
public class MarkingCriteria {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name="criteria")
        private String criteria;

        @Column(name="bn_criteria")
        private String bnCriteria;
}
```

> Result found as below

```
results = {ArrayList@12758}  size = 2
 0 = {$Proxy210@12766} "org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@1c56a65c"
 1 = {$Proxy210@12767} "org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap@31c7eaa"
```

Comment: **Shortly;** You have already done what you want to do! Since the working structure of projections is based on a proxy layer; You see it like this when you want to debug, but you can actually access and use it in `ResultDTO` type you want. Returning the result `List <ResultDTO>`, you can call `getId()` etc. from within.

Comment: Add a constructor to your DTO class, then use it in your query `select new com.example.ResultDTO(smc.id, c.class, s.subject, ...) from ...`

Comment: @Yann39 Constructor based projection is okay but I want to use native SQL here.